# Why is a foul bunt on strike three an out?

Tags: rules, baseball

Following up on "[Why does a foul ball not count as a third strike?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/119/why-does-a-foul-ball-not-count-as-a-third-strike)", I can understand caught fouls and foul tips being counted as strike 3. But what is the logic behind a 3rd strike foul bunt being an out? Bunts are some of the most exciting plays in baseball. Is this just to encourage good bunting skills?

Comment: Gamesmanship? Won't allow team to wear out opposing pitcher? That's the beauty of competitive sports.This is one of many reasons baseball is losing to NFL, NBA.. Soccer.

Comment: Just happened in 4th game of series. I, too, wondered what the reasoning was. Makes sense that a third foul bunt should count as a strike if it is easier to hit a bunt. Oh, and the reason baseball is not as popular as football and basketball in US is most people no longer work on the land. Our economical structures are reflected in our sports. Farming is more reflective of the rugged individualism of the 19th and 20th centuries. Just a thought.

Comment: Caught fouls are not strike three. They are regular "putouts" (catches) credited to the fielder who caught them, just as they would be in fair territory.

Comment: Just happened again in Game 7, 9th inning to the Cubs in the 2016 World Series against the Indians. Never seen it before now!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It is much easier to make contact with a pitch on a bunt than with a regular swing. The foul out on a bunt rule basically exists to speed up play and prevent gamesmanship on the part of the batter.

If the batter could always bunt on strike two then batters like the pitcher and other poor hitters would walk significantly more often because it is easier for them to make even a little contact with a decent pitch than it is for the pitcher to continue to throw strikes.

Comment: As an extension of that strategy a team could bunt with two strikes repeatedly to force a dominating pitcher out of the game due to exhaustion.